# Java + unicode + (console and/or SQL) = fail?

Tags: java, sql, unicode

This is frustrating. When I run the following program I see "Garci?a" in the console instead of "García", whereas if I run it in the Eclipse debugger, `garciaString` contains "García". What's going on? Is the problem in System.out? Do I have to configure it specially to print Unicode?

```
package com.example.unicode;

public class UnicodeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String garciaString = "Garci\u0301a";
        System.out.println(garciaString);
    }
}
```

*edit:* I figured maybe the console doesn't print the right value because of fonts. But I also get "Garci?a" inserted in an SQL database. Does JDBC + SQL handle Unicode? If not, how do I handle `INSERT INTO mydb (id, name) VALUES (1, "Garci\u0301a")`?

Comment: When you say "console" do you mean a command-line window?  If that's the case, the problem is that the command-line you're running it in does not support Unicode.

Comment: Is `name` an nvarchar or a varchar?

Comment: VARCHAR(4096) in MySQL -- I've never heard of nvarchar before. Darnit.

Comment: NVARCHAR should solve the SQL problem

Comment: OK, There is no "real" NVARCHAR in MySQL, instead they use charset collation; in mine it was the default `latin1_swedish_ci`. I just changed it to `utf8_general_ci`; hopefully that will work. Still not sure which other places in my data pipeline I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the Eclipse console is not using UTF-8 encoding. You have to change it in preferences. See [Getting Unicode output in Eclipse Console](http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/05/getting-unicode-output-in-eclipse.html) and [this](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/) article.

Comment: yep, ran into this issue before. here's a helpful link: [Eclipse – How to change the console output encoding](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/)

Answer (score 1):

There's problem with Eclipse console/system console etc. Java operates internally on Unicode, but with the output there is more trick.

Generally, if you output to file - always use `OutputStringWriter` ans specify proper encoding, but when you print to System.out, expect operating system-defined behaviour. Eclipse console may be configured, with Windows console it's a harder way. You can always direct standard output to file and see the results in unicode-handling editor such as **gedit** or **Notepad++**